# Modify Core Block Default Attributes

Tags: block-editor

I have a client that wants images to automatically be centered. This used to be possible with the `image_default_align` option for the old editor. Is there a simple way to change the default attributes for core blocks?

Comment: Gutenberg already have a align center option that appears on toolbar. You can add your editor styles via hook for some custom styling.

Comment: Thanks @MehmoodAhmad I know the center options is there. My clients wants center to be the default for the image block. I would like to change this default attribute.

Comment: I think it can be achievable via Block Filters (https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/), but I'm not sure. Still working on this myself.

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned in comments it is possible with Block Filters. Below is the code that allowes images to be automatically centered when inserted.

```
wp.hooks.addFilter( 'blocks.registerBlockType', 'misha/img', ( settings, name ) => {
    // so we check block name here if it is image we change attributes
    if( 'core/image' === name ) {

        return lodash.assign( {}, settings, {
            attributes: lodash.assign( {}, settings.attributes, { 
                align: {
                    type: 'string', 
                    default: 'center'
                } 
            } )
        } )
        
  }

  return settings
    
})
```

This code can be used in any JS file enqueued with `enqueue_block_editor_assets`, the code snippet I took from this guide https://rudrastyh.com/gutenberg/change-default-blocks-with-block-filters.html